# Making Huge application

Tags: ios, xcode, text, uilabel

Basically I want to make an app with a lot of screens (to present text), but that is about it.  It isn't complicated at all.  I don't want to have 100+ view controllers, so is there any pretty simple way to do this?

It would be an app where you read a page of text and then press the next button and read the next page.

What would be the best/cleanest way to do this?

Thank you,
-Joe

Comment: Why even need 100+ VC's if you could just set the text between about 4 or 5 of them based on user interaction?

Comment: Can you elaborate on HTML?

There would probably be three buttons for different subjects (see my answer below) but i would still need to present a lot of text in each of those 3.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the iOS review guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 2.21
>
> [...] Apps that are simply a book should be submitted to the
>   iBookstore.

Perhaps you should be writing this as a book instead of an app.

Comment: It is more like a study guide.  I thought a good way to study for finals would be to make a study guide (put in all of the information, and be able to scroll through the different pages).

Comment: I started reading the guidelines in the link you posted.  A lot of them are really funny.  

"Apps that duplicate apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra apps."

Comment: There are a lot of times I wish they would enforce their own guidelines better but it's good to see what they are so that you know the risks.

Comment: So what would be a smart way to do this? I would like flippable pages (like a book almost)